# What's a good Object/Array format to produce the following form?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a JSON that produces the following HTML form:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column row-inner">
        <label>First name</label>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="column row-inner">
        <label>Last name</label>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column row-inner">
        <label >Message</label>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-big row-inner">
        <label>Message</label>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="column row-inner">
        <label>Message</label>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="column row-inner">
        <label>Message</label>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

I thought of creating an array and have more arrays inside:

```
  schema: [{ // row
    [{ // row-inner
      name: 'First name', // label
      type: 'text', // input
    }, {
      name: 'Last name',
      type: 'text'
    }]
  }]
```

However, I find it overly complicated (I'm already confused myself).

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Just make it an array of arrays of objects! `[ [ {name: ..., type: ...}, {name: ..., type: ...} ], [ ... ], [ ... ], ... ]`

Comment: This is an invalid structure `[{[{....}]}]` you can make it an array of arrays if `schema` should contain multiple forms `var schema = [[{name:..., type:...}, ... ], [{name:.., type:...}, ... ] , ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// the form array
[
    // the first row
    [
        // the first column
        {
            // the label
            name: "First name",
            // the input
            type: "text"
        },
        // the second column
        {
            name: "Last name",
            type: "text"
        }
    ],
    // the second row
    [
        {
            name: "Message",
            type: "text"
        }
    ],
    // the third row
    [
        {
            name: "Message",
            type: "text"
        },
        {
            name: "Message",
            type: "text"
        },
        {
            name: "Message",
            type: "text"
        }
    ]
]
```

The **form** will be an array like this:

```
form = [row, row, row, row, ...]
```

where **row** is an array like this:

```
row = [column, column, column, ...]
```

and **column** is an object in this format:

```
column = {
    name: "label's text",
    type: "input's type"
}
```

**jQuery code to transform the above structure into a form:**

```
var form = ...;

var $form = $("<form></form>");
form.forEach(function(row) {
    var $row = $("<div></div>")
      .addClass("row")
      .appendTo($form);

    row.forEach(function(column) {
        var $column = $("<div></div>")
          .addClass("column row-inner")
          .appendTo($row);

        $("<label></label>").text(column.name).appendTo($column);
        $("<input/>").attr("type", column.type).appendTo($column);
    });
});

// append $form to a container
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an Array of Person Objects?

```
var people = [];

function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

var person = new Person('Foo', 'Bar');
people.push(person);

console.log(people[0]);
Person {firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar"}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q1a7k30L/